# Dojo Beginner: Hows do I make a custom Widget using _DomTemplated without getting a render error?

Tags: dojo

I am writing a custom Dojo Widget that uses the dojox.dtl._DomTemplated for DTL (Django Template Language) using the example [found here](http://view-source%3ahttp://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/dtl/demos/demo_DomTemplated_amd.html).  Basically, I am looking to have a widget that will either display or not display a set of buttons/links depending on the values set on the Widget.  However, when I try to run my custom component, I get some strange pukage:

> You cannot use the Render object without specifying where you want to render it

Which is occurring on line 3648 of [dojo.js.uncompressed.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js).

My Widget is pretty simple, and I have tried using an external template file and defining the templateString directly in the Widget JS file.

Here is the widget code, as I currently have it:
    // img.ArtThumbnailWidget
    dojo.provide("img.ArtThumbnailWidget");

```
// Create the widget
require([
         "dojo/_base/declare",
         "dijit/_WidgetBase",
         "dojox/dtl/_DomTemplated",
         "dojo/text!img/ArtThumbnailWidget/templates/ArtThumbnailWidget.html",
         "dojo/parser",
         "dojox/dtl/tag/logic"
    ], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _DomTemplated, template) {

    dojo.declare("img.ArtThumbnailWidget",[dijit._WidgetBase, _DomTemplated], {
        /* Our properties will go here */

        // Art JSON object, default is null
        art: null,

        // Viewer ID (the username of the person looking at this image), which will default to null
        viewerId: null,

        // maxSize is how large of an image to return.  The back-end will resize the thumbnail accordingly
        maxSize: 100,

        // Our template - important!
        templateString: template,

        // A class to be applied to the root node in our template
        baseClass: "artThumbnailWidget",

        _dijitTemplateCompat: true,

        widgetsInTemplate: true,

        /* This is called once the DOM structure is ready, but before anything is shown */
        postCreate: function() {
            // Get a DOM node reference for the root of our widget
            var domNode = this.domNode;

            // Run any parent postCreate processes - can be done at any point
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        /* This is called anytime the "art" attribute is set.  Consider is a "setter" method */
        _setArtAttr: function(av) {
            if (av != null) {
                // Save it on our widget instance - note that
                // we're using _set, to support anyone using
                // our widget's Watch functionality, to watch values change
                this._set("art", av);

                // Using our avatarNode attach point, set its src value
                this.thumbnailNode.src = av.url+"?maxSize="+this.maxSize;
                this.thumbnailNode.alt = av.title;
            } else {
                // We could have a default here...would be an error, since we
                // shouldn't be calling this without an art object
            }
        },

        _setMaxSizeAttr: function(ms) {
            // Save it on our widget instance - note that
            // we're using _set, to support anyone using
            // our widget's Watch functionality, to watch values change
            this._set("maxSize", ms);

            this.thumbnailNode.width = ms;
            this.thumbnailNode.height = ms;
        },
    });     // End of the widget

});
```

And here is the Template:

```
<div dojoAttachPoint="containerNode">
    <img class="${baseClass}Thumbnail" src="" alt="" data-dojo-attach-point="thumbnailNode" />
    <% if viewerId == art|owner|name %>
        <p>test</p>
    <% endif %>
</div>
```

In addition to trying to define the template directly in the Widget JS code, I have also tried simplifying the template by removing all the DTL tags in it.  The Widget works fine if I use the standard _TemplateMixin instead of dojox.dtl._DomTemplated, except that the DTL doesn't get rendered, its just displayed as text.  I have also tried using the dojox.dtl._Templated, but I get the same error.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use DTL? If not, I recommend using the standard mechanism of Dojo widgets - which is to use a HTML fragment in a template HTML and use dijit._TemplatedMixin to help with the DOM creation for the widget. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/writingWidgets.html for a good description on implementing custom widgets

Comment: Well, I was looking for a solution to allow me to switch the content of the template based on values set on the Widget.  I am not married to DTL at all.  Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is to have a set of buttons that appear in the Widget under certain circumstances.  The only other way I know to do this is to add the dynamic content to the dom at the postCreate:.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that I have a Widget working using TemplatedMixin.  Again, the "switch" to _DomTemplated was to accommodate a need to have conditional statements control how the DOM is built in the template.

Comment: ah - yes we had a similar need and we ended up using programmatic DOM creation instead of putting conditions inside the template. So basically you can have attachpoints inside the template and then replace that node with your own DOM in the postCreate() lifecycle method - u can have all the logic you want based on user params etc in that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old question, but I was looking into how to do this for myself. Thanks for the example, I got it to work.

It turns out you are using the wrong template tags. Use {} instead of <>

```
{% if viewerId == art|owner|name %}
     <p>test</p>
{% endif %}
```

For displaying variable contents:

```
{{ varName }}
```

The regular dojo template mechanism ${varName} means nothing in a DTL template.